# How to access camera in docker with intellij idea

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

I want to read the stream from a camera using python3 with an opencv-python3 docker and intellij idea. I found that most people say that run docker with `--device /dev/video0` option, but I can't found where to add the options in intellij idea. How can I access camera in docker with intellij idea?

Comment: Have you tried to add it to the  "Command line options" field in docker run configuration: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker.html#add_command_options_for_container ?

Comment: I found that when I click run, the intellij idea will create a new docker container and run the code in it instead of the container I configure the "Command line options". And about adding a python SDK in the project structure part, I only can select a docker image without any options but not a docker container. @y.bedrov